# Make index.html that is in /views folder as landing page on webserver

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I want to upload my files to a webserver where index.html is required in the root-folder to act like a landing page. The way my code is now, my index.html has to be in the /views folder. Is there any way to make it land on index.html or do I have to move it out and change the code (if so, how?) I am using html/css, node.js and express. Not very good with the last 2, but 'had to' because I am connecting to a database. Can someone help me out?

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/public
  /styles
    styles.css
/views
  index.html
  twitter.html
server.js
package.json
```

**script.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
let db

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://someuser:somepassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017/twitter?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/twitter', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.render('twitter', {tweets: result})
  })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.render('index');
   });

app.post('/tweets', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/twitter')
  })
})
```

index.html is linking to twitter.html. If I were to move index.html to the rootfolder, should I link to the website like this? `views/twitter`.

Comment: I think we'd need more information about the webserver you mentioned. If it's configured as a reverse proxy for your Express app then you shouldn't need to change anything. If it's serving up files directly from the file-system then how is that supposed to interact with your Express app? What makes you think you need `index.html` in the root folder?

Comment: You could always do a redirect to the views/index.html from the index.html in the root directory...that's easy-peasy

Comment: @skirtle I don't know if I _have to_ have index.html, but the way the folder structure is now, when I upload them to the webfolder it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/aSlOe . I don't know much about the webserver, my school let's everyone have their own webfolder, where they can upload their files to make a webpage. Until I worked with database, I have just used html/css where I put index.html in the root-folder, but now with databases and Express etc, I am a little lost. If I run script.js, it works correctly on localhost and the 'landing page' is index.html.

Comment: @racecarjonathan I did that, but then I met another problem: when I click the links on views/index.html, I get "Not Found, The requested URL /twitter was not found on this server."  Because of Express, they are linked like this `<li><a href="/twitter">Tweet!</a></li>`. I don't know if it's related to the problem I am asking, because it works perfectly on localhost!

Comment: @racecarjonathan Was just wondering if I can make index in views as landing page without extra files, but that's basically the answer. Thanks!